# how to print struct timeVal

Tags: c, sockets, unix, gcc, gcc-warning

i have this line in my code

```
`printf("Rcvd pkt from %s:%d at <%ld.%06ld>\n", inet_ntoa(servAddr.sin_addr),  ntohs(servAddr.sin_port), timeVal.tv_sec, timeVal.tv_usec);`
```

this is the warning i get with gcc while compiling it

```
`cc1: warnings being treated as errors
`client12.c: In function ‘main’:
`client12.c:131: warning: format ‘%06ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 5 has type ‘__darwin_suseconds_t’
`client12.c:131: warning: format ‘%06ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 5 has type ‘__darwin_suseconds_t’
```

what am i doing wrong??

PS - i have included `time.h`  and `sys/time.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the numbers to the correct types:

```
printf("Rcvd pkt from %s:%d at <%ld.%06ld>\n", inet_ntoa(servAddr.sin_addr),  ntohs(servAddr.sin_port), (long int)(timeVal.tv_sec), (long int)(timeVal.tv_usec));
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Casting it to long int worked. Why can't we standardize these across all systems.

Comment: Mainly because C is intended to be portable to a fairly wide range of systems.  It runs on systems where the maximum data size is 32 bits and ones where it could be 128 bits or more.  For 64-bit systems, you want a 64-bit `time_t` and related types (so that you don't run out of time in 2038), but the systems that C was originally written for couldn't (easily) address data types that large.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the members of struct timeval will vary from system to system.  As with many other C data types, the safe and portable thing to do is to cast the values when printing them:

```
printf("Rcvd pkt from %s:%d at <%ld.%06ld>\n",
    inet_ntoa(servAddr.sin_addr),  ntohs(servAddr.sin_port),
    (long) timeVal.tv_sec, (long) timeVal.tv_usec);
```

This will work correctly for any data type smaller than or equal in size to a long.  And this idiom is so common that people will think twice about making any of these common data types longer than a long, although be careful with data types that refer to file sizes (like off_t); those could be `long long` in some cases.

To be maximally safe, you'd cast to `long long` and use a `%lld` format, but that swaps one portability problem for another, since not all `printf` implementations support `%lld` yet.  And I've not seen an implementation where those time values require that treatment.

Answer (score 1):

See [sys/types.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html) for an explanation of `suseconds_t`. Apparently, it is

> a signed integral type capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, 1,000,000].

This means it might defined as an `int` on your system. Try removing the long specifier `l` from the format string and just print it as a regular decimal.

**Edit**

As per rra's answer, this will not be portable. It will only work on systems that define `suseconds_t` in the same way. We know from the spec that the type is a signed integral type of at least 32 bits. The most portable way is to cast it to the biggest signed integral intrinsic that you can get away with.